# accessing class in another method, from a override method

Tags: java

I have a class `CircularList` and `LinkedListReferenceBased`... most of my methods are in LinkedListReference based. I have overridden the method remove in Circular List.... in my method I have a method called `find()` and it is in `LinkedListReferenceBased`... and when I used the method remove in `CirclarList` from the overridden method remove I get this error?

```
cannot find symbol
    Node prev = find(index-1);
                ^
  symbol:   method find(int)
  location: class CircularList
```

### 1 error

```
CIRCULARLIST

public void remove(int index){
super.remove(index);

System.out.println("-------");
int num = index;
while(size>0){

    //System.out.println("strt");
    if(index>= 0 /*&& index < size*/){
      if(index == 0) {
      //delete the first node from the list
      System.out.println("REMOVED :"+head.item());//----------------EXR
      head = head.getNext();
    }
    else {
        Node prev = find(index-1);

        // delete the node after the node that prev
        //references, save regerence to node
        Node curr = prev.getNext();

        System.out.println(curr.item());
            if(size > 1){

        }
        else{
            System.out.print("is the last one left");
        }
        prev.setNext(curr.getNext());
        curr = prev.getNext();

        index+=num-1;

        }//end if
           size--;
    //System.out.println(size+" <-size || index-> " +index);

          }//end if

    }

}//end remove
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: is `find` in `LinkedListReferenceBased` private? does it accept a `int` argument?

Comment: Since we can't see the class definition it's also worth asking if you remembered the extension: `public class CircularList extends LinkedListReferencedBase`?

Comment: @egracer yes the find method is already declared in ListReferenceBased, how would i get to that

Comment: @egracer yes i did use extends....

Comment: you need to make sure the find method is public or protected

Comment: @cmehmen Can you post the method definition for `find` in `LinkedListReferencedBase`?

Comment: @egracer https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qtpgbmu9oinw9l/ListReferenceBased.java?dl=0

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ and @l-l are right – your method is defined as `private Node find(int index)`, which is why you can't access it in your subclass. You need to change it to either `protected Node find(int index)` or `public Node find(int index)`. Methods marked as `private` are not accessible in subclasses. Make sure you post all of the relevant code in future questions so we can help you out!